# Same xcodebuild command run on azure pipeline and local machine end up with a small diff - and is not runnable

Tags: xcode, azure-pipelines, xcodebuild

so building a MainFramework.framework which embeds 4 more frameworks so the structure MainFramework.framework setup looks like

- MainFramework.framework

  - FrameworkA.framework (embedded, linked)
  - FrameworkB.framework (embedded, linked)
  - FrameworkC.framework (embedded, linked)
  - FrameworkD.framework (embedded, linked)
  - lib.a (linked)

Now, I run the same command on my local machine and on azure pipeline

`xcodebuild clean build -scheme SDK -workspace SDK-App.xcworkspace -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos -derivedDataPath derived_data ARCHS=arm64 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO`

Build succeeds on both environments, however, if I start to compare the output from both, there is always a size 2kB difference in every executable file,

Now if I want to use this MainFramework.framework (which comes from `/derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MainFramework.framework` on both environments the only one that is working - no surprise - is the one from the local build

So, I started to experiment, I started to use the framework that comes from azure build - the one that is not being able to resolve in the target app - that the target app was not able to resolve it and ending up with *Required module 'FrameworkA','FrameworkB',... not found*

Now, if I copy/replace only ONE file - MainFramework.framework/Modules/MainFramework.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule - do a copy from **local MainFramework.framework** to **Azure MainFramework.framework**  - everything works. Modules are being resolved in the target app and I can run the sample app consuming the functionality of MainFramework.framework

My question is - what I am doing wrong? I spend couple of hours and I was not able to find a solution.

Update: Added Gist https://gist.github.com/ivanpagac/d1aedb833629e6f4ab2ca249c167ce81

Comment: Hi @Ivan, could you set the variable system.debug to true, then share the pipeline definition and detail log here? Thanks. In addition, you do a copy form local MainFramework.framework to Azure MainFramework.framework, the file is arm64.swiftmodule, right?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, thanks for the response. I download the azure build artifact (framework) and replace arm64.swiftmodule from local build. Attachet gist from azure.But it looks same except that iam building parallel on local machine but otherwise looks good.

Comment: Hi @lvan, It seems that the log you shared is a success log, could you check it again?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, the gist is from the azure pipeline, the build succeed as is mentioned in the question. however I am not able to use the artefact produced in my target app. The pipeline is just a xcode build and copy/publish, nothing more/nothing less. The problem is I am not able to use the artefact from azure pipeline in TargetApp.

Comment: Hi @lvan, Sorry for my misunderstanding, could you re-describe more details about scenario? You cannot use the artifact from azure pipeline in TargetApp, you publish the artifact in the build pipeline and then cannot use the artifact in the Azure DevOps release pipeline, right? If yes, could you share the error log here?